# Using sed to pull out the last parts of a string

Tags: regex, string, windows, awk, sed

I'm sure there must be a simple answer to this, but I'm having trouble working it out and the similar questions I've found here aren't quite getting me across the line (though they have helped).

I have a TestFile.txt text file in Windows with a varying number of OU's per line as follows:

```
"CN=John Doe,OU=Milk,OU=Dairy,OU=Food,DC=company,DC=com"
"CN=Jane Doe,OU=Red,OU=Apples,OU=Fruit,OU=Food,DC=company,DC=com"
"CN=Pete Doe,OU=Forks,OU=Cutlery,OU=NotFood,DC=company,DC=com"
"CN=Fred Doe,OU=Spoons,OU=Cutlery,OU=NotFood,DC=company,DC=com"
"CN=Alex Doe,OU=Biscuits,OU=Chocolate,OU=Candy,OU=Food,DC=company,DC=com"
"CN=Peta Doe,OU=Buttons,OU=Chocolate,OU=Candy,OU=Food,DC=company,DC=com"
```

I want to strip the extraneous data such that I am left with only the last two OUs like this:

```
OU=Dairy,OU=Food
OU=Fruit,OU=Food
OU=Cutlery,OU=NotFood
OU=Cutlery,OU=NotFood
OU=Candy,OU=Food
OU=Candy,OU=Food
```

I've stripped out the start and end of each line easily enough with the following using the Windows port of sed:

```
sed -e "s/[^,]*,//" -e "s/,DC\=.*//" TestFile.txt
```

...which gives me:

```
OU=Milk,OU=Dairy,OU=Food
OU=Red,OU=Apples,OU=Fruit,OU=Food
OU=Forks,OU=Cutlery,OU=NotFood
OU=Spoons,OU=Cutlery,OU=NotFood
OU=Biscuits,OU=Chocolate,OU=Candy,OU=Food
OU=Buttons,OU=Chocolate,OU=Candy,OU=Food
```

So now I just need to isolate the last two OU's on each line and ignore everything else. If I had a fixed number of OU's for each line, that would simplify things a lot, but how do I make a sed expression to accommodate a varying number of OU's?

Comment: add awk to tags and if possible refresh the question. with awk it's very simple

Comment: Ah, you mean something like: gawk -F, "{ print $(NF-1), $NF; }" TestFile.txt ??

Comment: quick learner looks fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/.*(OU=[^,]*,OU=[^,]*),DC=.*/\1/' file
```

Output:

```
OU=Dairy,OU=Food
OU=Fruit,OU=Food
OU=Cutlery,OU=NotFood
OU=Cutlery,OU=NotFood
OU=Candy,OU=Food
OU=Candy,OU=Food
```

Comment: I like that - a lot cleaner and only one command too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to josifoski, I've got it:

```
cat TestFile.txt | sed -e "s/[^,]*,//" -e "s/,DC\=.*//" | gawk -F, "{ print $(NF-1), $NF; }"
```

Perfect, thanks. =)

Comment: (a) You get a UUoC (Useless Use of `cat`) award for using `cat` when there is absolutely no need.  (b) You shouldn't really need to use both `sed` and `awk`; either can do the job on its own.

Comment: Still learning this stuff. =) Cyrus posted the best solution in the end. Makes more sense now after reading the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that after the final OU of each line will always be only two more fields. This might be a solution in AWK. Just AWK.

```
awk -F, '{OU=$(NF-3)","$(NF-2); print OU}' file > outfile
```

Which outputs:

```
OU=Dairy,OU=Food
OU=Fruit,OU=Food
OU=Cutlery,OU=NotFood
OU=Cutlery,OU=NotFood
OU=Candy,OU=Food
OU=Candy,OU=Food
```